# How to add any reusable interface for an ActiveX control using MFC?

Tags: c++, properties, interface, mfc, activex

I have an ActiveX control container that only accepts a predefined set of interfaces (properties). I need to design quite a few MFC ActiveX controls that expose those properties, so my initial attempt was to create an interface class that contains all the required properties as pure virtual members and all my ActiveX control inherit from this interface class. Now my ActiveX control have all the interfaces inherited, but how can I expose them to the container? If I use the class wizard to add those properties, I know I can expose them. But the whole point is to avoid adding them one by one for each ActiveX control. If I don't use the class wizard, this will mean that I have to manually modify the BEGIN_DISPATCH_MAP() & END_DISPATCH_MAP() section and the corresponding .ODL file, which I don't think is a good thing to do.

So my question is, using MFC, how can I inherit an abstract class (interface class) to implement all the predefined properties (interfaces) for an ActiveX control and expose them to the user?

Example:
Say my base class A has a property defined as: long newProperty. And my ActiveX control B inherit from A, so B also has newProperty. My question is how to expose newProperty in B? How can I have get and set functions for this new property like using the Class Wizard? And do I have to manually modify BEGIN_DISPATCH_MAP() & END_DISPATCH_MAP() section and the corresponding .ODL file?

Answer (score 0):

You want to access ActiveX controls programmatically, not using class wizard generated wrappers, if I understand you correctly? Well, this is a bit cumbersome. For example, this calls a member funktion MyMemberFunction with `long` parameter 123456789:

```
AtlAxWinInit();
pMyActiveXWnd = new CAxWindow();
pMyActiveXWnd ->Create(...)
LPUNKNOWN pUnk;
pMyActiveXWnd ->QueryControl(&pUnk);    
IDispatch *spDispatch; 
HRESULT hRes = pUnk->QueryInterface(__uuidof(spDispatch), (void **) &spDispatch);   
DISPID dispid;
DISPPARAMS dispparams = { NULL, NULL, 0, 0 };
VARIANT vRet;
COleVariant vParam((long)123456789,VT_I4);
EXCEPINFO excepinfo;
UINT nArgErr;
dispparams.rgvarg = (LPVARIANT)vParam;
dispparams.cArgs = 1;
dispparams.cNamedArgs = 0;
hRes = spDispatch->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, _T("MyMemberFunction"), 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &dispid);
hRes = spDispatch->Invoke(dispid, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &dispparams, &vRet, &excepinfo, &nArgErr);
```

Comment: No, I want to expose the properties (interfaces) of my ActiveX control and at the same time have all those exposed properties inherited from a base class. Say my base class A has a property defined as: long newProperty. And my ActiveX control B inherit from A, so B also has newProperty. My question is how to expose newProperty in B?

Comment: The concept of virtual members comes from the C++ world, so I was assuming you work with some kind of self-created wrapper. C++ lacks dynamic typing. If you want it, you have to provide some kind of interpreter to access inherited members in your ActiveX control to 'emulate' dynamic typing, i.e. using OLE variants by querying the com interface the was I described above.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. My problem is I don't know how to expose the inherited members to the user without Class Wizard. But your answer is to tell me how to access those members. I can't access them if I even don't know how to expose them.

Comment: Sorry, I think I don't really grasp what you are up to. I only can guess. But if I'm right you want to generate the interfaces at compile time somehow. This would require complex scripting, which I really don't recommend. Maybe you should use .NET for your second-level controls as .NET includes reflection and embedded compiling abilities so you can dynamically generate interfaces as you see fit. You can use these via com interoperability. But I cannot even imagine a scenario where this effort falls on fertil ground and suspect you should consider a general redesign.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not an option for me. We are dealing with legacy code and we can't afford a redesign or migrate to .NET.

Comment: Then I suggest you look for a scripting engine to generate the interface source code of the new ActiveX members inherited from your base control. For backward compatibility, I'd rather create a complete new control for each version and ActiveX.